# what is the Best way detect a video playback state in WebView?

Tags: android, webview, kotlin

What is the best way detect a video playback state in a WebView?
I'm using a flag and detect a video playback state in `onProcessChanged` 
But I think this is not a good way. 
Is there a more efficient way? not using a `javaScriptInterface`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved myself.
Using `JavaScript` & `Jquery` is the best way.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51298181/9601667